# How to make an array unique if all elements are same in array, Ruby?

Tags: ruby

using `Ruby 2.0`

```
if

array_a = [360,370,360,350,360,360,360]

output : array_a = [360,370,360,350,360,360,360]

if 

array_a = [360,360,360,360]

output : array_a = [360]
```

If all elements are same then only unique array should come, else same array.

I am trying to implement this logic but not able any hint please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array#uniq`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-uniq), checking if result array's size is 1:

```
uniq_array_a = array_a.uniq
output = uniq_array_a.one? ? uniq_array_a : array_a
```

Comment: Instead of `array_a.uniq.count == 1` you can do `array_a.uniq.one?`

Comment: Nice Thanks @BroiSatse and Marek Lipka

Comment: I noticed the downvote. How could I improve my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `array_a.uniq`

For example:

`a = [10, 20, 30, 10, 20]
a.uniq # => [10, 20, 30]`

Comment: If all elements are same in an array then only i want unique array else same as array whatever is there

Comment: Yeah, i got it :-) You should go with the answer of Marek Lipka!